# Saving multiple model using array

Tags: laravel

Basically, I  have an array of `$course_id`. I want to save multiple times according to number of `$course_id`

Here is my code:

```
$courselist[] = new Courselist;

for($i=0;$i<count($course_id);$i++)
{
    $comparelist = Courselist::select('course_id','internal','external')
            ->where('course_id','=',$course_id[$i])
            ->get();
                        
if($comparelist->isEmpty())
{
    $courselist[$i]->course_id = $course_id[$i];
    $courselist[$i]->internal = $internal;
    $courselist[$i]->external = $external;
    $courselist[$i]->save();
}
}
```

Does anyone know how can I save this?

Comment: Why are you checking the data before saving? Is there any logic? and what output are you getting out of this code? Where you are getting error?

Comment: i am checking for any duplicate of `course_id` and I got error `Creating default object from empty value` this is the line:`$courselist[$i]->course_id = $course_id[$i];`

Comment: Is `course_id` a primary key?

Comment: its secondary key...btw I solve it using `insert()`. Thank you so much for help :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `updateOrCreate()` function like this

```php
for ($i = 0; $i < count($course_id); $i++) {

    Courselist::updateOrCreate([
        ['course_id' => $course_id[$i]],
        [
            'internal' => $internal,
            'external' => $external
        ],
    ]);
}
```

ref link https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#upserts

Answer (score 0):

I use `insert()`  function and it works

```
for($i=0;$i<count($course_id);$i++)
{
$data[] = array(
         'course_id' => $course_id[$i],
         'internal' => $internal,
         'external' => $external
         );
}
Courselist::insert($data);
```